# How to use the Phillips-Perron and Dickey-Fuller unit root test to test for AR(1) or Ornstein-Uhlenbeck process

Tags: time-series, stochastic-processes, unit-root, augmented-dickey-fuller

My question comes from this [paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1905.09647) (p. 10), where the authors say:

> The $\ln(\hat{p_t}) - \ln(p_t) \sim AR(1)$ condition expresses that the LPPLS fitting residuals can be modeled by a mean-reversal Ornstein-Uhlenbeck (O-U) process when the logarithmic price in the bubble regime is attributed to a deterministic LPPLS component. Since the test for the O-U property of LPPLS fitting residuals can be translated into an AR(1) test for the corresponding residuals, both the Phillips-Perron unit-root test and the Dickey-Fuller unit-root test are used to check the O-U property of LPPLS fitting residuals. In this study, the 5% significant level is applied in the tests.

$\ln(\hat{p_t}) - \ln(p_t)$ are the residuals between the log-values of a fitted curve ($\hat{p}_t$) and the observed log-values ($p_t$).

From my understanding the authors use the Phillips-Perron (PP) and Dickey-Fuller (DF) unit-root tests to test if the residuals $\ln(\hat{p_t}) - \ln(p_t)$ satisfy an AR(1) or O-U process.

I know that the unit-root test checks, if for a given AR(1) process:

$$
y_t = \theta y_{t-1} + \epsilon_t
$$
one of the following conditions hold:

$$
\begin{align}
H_0: \theta=1 \\
H_A: \theta<1
\end{align}
$$
If $H_0$ is accepted, the process is non-stationary.

I'm also aware, that an AR(1) process is the time-discrete version of an Ornstein-Uhlenbeck process.

**The actual question:** I can't see how the two tests (PP and DF) can tell me if the residuals $\ln(\hat{p_t}) - \ln(p_t)$ satisfy an AR(1) or O-U process, since from my understanding they just check if a specific property (non-stationarity) of the processes is satisfied.

In other words: For what purpose are the authors using the PP and DF tests? It seems to me they are using both tests to test wether the residuals can be modeled with a AR(1) / O-U process. But from my understanding that is not what can be tested using the PP / DK tests.

Comment: Quick answer: Yes, you are correct these test are unit root tests.

Comment: @HartoSaarinen I know that they are unit root tests, but why should they tell me if the data is actually an AR(1) or O-U process?

Comment: They don’t tell you that. They assume the AR model. Of course you could use a different model and then you have some different tests. But AR (and/or MA ) models are the most basic and usually the place to start.

Comment: @HartoSaarinen OK, that is also my line of reasoning. But for that purpose are the authors then using the PP and ADF tests?

Comment: Well usually the OU process is assumed to be mean reverting. So I guess they want to verify that their AR1 process really is also.

Comment: So they check if the process doesn't have a unit root, which makes it stationary and equivalent to a mean-reverting process. Is that correct?

Comment: That is what I think they mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a stochastic process $X$ of the form:

$$
X_t = \alpha_0 + \psi X_{t-1} + \epsilon_t
$$

where $\epsilon_t$ is white noise, the null hypothesis for the Dickey-Fuller test is

$$
H_0 : \psi = 1
$$

whereas

$$
H_A : \psi < 1 \, .
$$

In case $H_0$ cannot be rejected, the process is non-stationary and a random walk with drift. In case $H_0$ is rejected, the process is stationary and an AR(1)-process and also a time-discrete O-U process.

Comment: You might want to correct your terminology "$H_{0}$ is accepted".